# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type 'crmWebService.ArrayOfInt'

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception, casting

I'm getting an error after sending a list to a web service.

This is the code that is calling the web service:

```
Dim sProgramInterest As New List(Of Integer)    
crmService.InsertProspectGetId(sProgramInterest.ToList)
```

But I'm getting this error.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' to type 'crmWebService.ArrayOfInt'.

The parameter being accepted by the web service is:

```
ByVal sProgramInterest As List(Of Integer)
```

Comment: looks like crmWebService.ArrayOfInt is a custom type. Can you post the definition of it? rightclick on InsertProspectGetId and go to definition. its parameter is of type ArrayOfInt go to its definition and can you post it?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of calling `ToList`, call `ToArray`:

```
crmService.InsertProspectGetId(sProgramInterest.ToArray)
```

Comment: when i do that --- i get this error Error 1 Value of type '1-dimensional array of Integer' cannot be converted to 'crmWebService.ArrayOfInt'

Comment: @JeremyLewallen - OK. My assumption that `ArrayOfInt` was an array of integers seems to be incorrect. What is `crmWebService.ArrayOfInt`? How is it defined?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that service accepts array of int, not list of int. Thus try:

```
crmService.InsertProspectGetId(sProgramInterest.ToArray())
```

Comment: I think your answer is in C#. should be `ToArray` for vb.net

Comment: @Youssef - You are incorrect. Both `ToArray` and `ToArray()` work in VB.NET. When a method call is parameterless, the `()` are optional in VB.NET.

Comment: @Youssef: Last time I used VB.NET is was accepting both styles - with brackets and without, so it was optional. IMO that ugly and erases VB.NET programmers brain.

Comment: good to know. thanks. I never worked with VB.NET but I know there are a lot less {} and () than C#. Didn't know that both are supported

Comment: when i do that --- i get this error Error 1 Value of type '1-dimensional array of Integer' cannot be converted to 'crmWebService.ArrayOfInt'

Comment: @Jeremy: please clarify the type accepted by your service. Please post the contract code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'd have to do something like,

```
Dim sProgramInterest As New crmWebService.ArrayOfInt    
crmService.InsertProspectGetId(sProgramInterest)
```

Based on the error, the parameter has to be the `crmWebService.ArrayOfInt` type. You'll have to use that class instead of a `List(Of Integer)`.